# grep like command to find matching lines plus neighbourhood lines

Tags: bash, grep

**grep** command is really powerful and I use it a lot.

Sometime I have the necessity to find something with grep looking inside many many files to find the string I barely remember helping myself with **-i** (ignore case) option, **-r** (recursive) and also **-v** (exclude).

But what I really need is to have a special output from grep which highlight the matching line(s) plus the **neighbourhood lines** (given the matching line I'd like to see, let's say, the 2 preceding and the 2 subsequent lines).

Is there a way to get this result using bash?

Comment: On side note, what operating system are you running? Solaris 10 for example has a VERY limited grep that can't do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

most greps allow the "context" flag making it a bit more readable:

```
grep --context=3 foo myfile.txt
```

Comment: great, that was even clearer then the first answer. And it is exactly what I was looking for. @Gringo Suave, this is the non contracted form of your -C option.

Answer (score 22):

[Grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) itself will do this

```
grep -A 2 -B 2 foo myfile.txt
```

Comment: And don't forget `-C 2` which means `-A 2 -B 2`.

Answer (score 7):

You can omit -C

```
grep -2 foo myfile.txt
```

is equal to

```
grep -C 2 foo myfile.txt
```